# JQuery Check Input File

Tags: jquery, file-upload, validation

I have file input fields in a group like below. I'd like all of them to be required fields.

```
<!-- file upload group -->
<div class="Fieldset FileUpGroup">
  <span class="Legend">File Upload Group: (required)</span>
  <input name="fileUploads[]" type="file">
  <input name="fileUploads[]" type="file">
  <input name="fileUploads[]" type="file">
</div>
```

I have the following JQuery to validate, but it only validates the first one.

```
$('.FileUpGroup').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('input[type=file]').val() == '') { 
        Response('- Upload file not selected!', true);
        $(this).addClass('Error').fadeOut().fadeIn();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('Error');
    }
});
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using `each()` on the wrong element:

```
$('input[type="file"]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() == '') { 
        Response('- Upload file not selected!', true);
        $this.addClass('Error').fadeOut().fadeIn();
        return false;
    } else {
        $this.removeClass('Error');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` only returns the first value.
In your loop `($('.FileUpGroup').each)` is only activated for one item...
the `DIV.FileUpGroup` element.
`$('.FileUpGroup input[type=file]')` will find all the items and then iterates them one at a time
Here is an example. Hope I have been useful.

```
$('.FileUpGroup input[type=file]').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === '') {
        // wabba dabba do
    }
    else {
        // badda bawwa do
    }
});
```